# How to check page response HTML in Chrome developer tool

Tags: firebug, google-chrome-devtools

When debugging the page, in Firebug NET tab, it can show the page HTML, like the screenshot below. I was wondering if Chrome developer tool can do the same?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Chrome Dev Tool, under the resources or network tab, if you double click on a resource it will open it in a new tab/window showing the rendered HTML/page/image/etc.

If you want the HTML *code* you can look at the content tab under the Network pane, or you can look at the parsed/organized HTML code under the Elements pane.